# How to register a user event defined in a SUB VI(LabVIEW)

Tags: labview

I created a SUB VI and defined a user event in it.
Then I created another VI, let's call it MAIN VI.
I put a SUB VI in the MAIN VI,and I want to register the user event created in the SUB VI to the Event Case in the MAIN VI, what should I do?

Comment: As srm notes it is *much better* (meaning easier to understand, and less surprising, to anyone else who looks at your code) to create the event in the caller VI and pass its refnum to the subVI. Is there any good reason you can't do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but it takes effort. What you are attempting to do is generally a bad idea -- as you can see from how much fighting against LabVIEW you have to do in the steps below. But because it is sometimes (rarely) necessary, I'll tell you how to do it. In general, though, when you have to fight this much, you may want to reconsider and let the caller VI be the one that allocates the event refnum and then pass it into the subVI, and only let the subVI generate the events.

Anyway... here's what you're asking for...

### Option 1

Step one: In the caller VI, use "Obtain Queue" and create a queue of the user event type (that means you need to drop a constant of the desired event refnum type wired to the "Obtain Queue" element type terminal).

Step two: Add the queue to the connector pane of the subVI and wire your created queue to the new terminal on the subVI.

Step three: Modify the subVI so that after you create the user event, use "Enqueue Element" to enqueue that user event into the queue.

Step four: Back in the caller VI, in **parallel** to the call to the subVI, do a "Dequeue Element". Now you have the user event in the caller.

Step five: Use Release Queue in the caller VI to release the queue.

Step six: In the caller VI, use "Register For Events" to register the user event. Now you are ready to receive the event in an Event structure.

**NOTE:** The above process gives *no guarantee* that the caller VI will register the event before the subVI starts sending events. If the subVI starts sending events before the Register For Events node is called, you'll miss those initial events. You need a second signaling mechanism to tell the subVI "ok, it's safe to proceed".

### Option 2

Step one: Put a giant case structure around all the code in your subVI. Wire the ? terminal of the case structure with a Boolean control. Add that Boolean control to the connector pane of the subVI. Now all the code for the subVI is in the TRUE case of the structure.

Step two: In the FALSE case, put the code to create the user event. Create an indicator of the user event and put it on the connector pane.

Step three: Use a Feedback Node *outside* of the case structure to store the user event. Do not provide any initialization of the Feedback Node.

Step three: In the caller, call the subVI with a FALSE wired to its input. The subVI will allocate the event refnum and return it to you. It will also store the refnum in the Feedback Node.

Step four: Use the Register For Events node to register the event in the caller VI.

Step five: Call the subVI a second time, this time passing TRUE. It will get the value of the user event refnum from the Feedback Node.

**NOTE:** This version DOES provide protection against missing the first events.

Comment: Took Option1,Thank you!

Comment: Option 1 is ugly, but option 2 is *terrible*. I think I'm going to have nightmares about it tonight. Readers, please *never do this*. +1 for answering the question though!

Comment: @nekomatic I already requested programmers try to avoid the whole setup, but if they're going to do it, they really need a solution that avoids the race condition. If you have a third option that avoids the race, please post it. But if ugly is the only solution that works, I advocate the working version over the pretty-but-flawed.

Comment: I was being slightly tongue-in-cheek: I can't think of a solution that doesn't involve either polling something or using two communication channels. I may post one later if I get to it. Uninitialised feedback nodes or shift registers have their own issues though, especially during development.

Comment: Actually, reading your option 2 more carefully, it's not as horrible as I thought. If you replace the Boolean case selector with a typedef enum whose states are (e.g.) `Initialise Event` and `Run` then it's *almost* OK. Needless to say the subVI must have error in/out which you use to make sure that the initialise call runs before the Register for Events which runs before the Run subVI call. But if you're doing it that way... why not just create the event in the caller and pass it to the subVI? :-?

Answer (score 0):

The Option 2 does not need the Boolean Control (at least with LabVIEW 2018+) - the subVI may use First Call function, and when it returns True, setup everything its caller needs (maybe the event refnum is not the only thing needed - maybe an empty cluster of a type which will be used to pass the data later) and return - the caller gets and processes it all, then invokes the subVI again; then the First Call returns False, and the subVI stays active "forever".

An alternative is to use two subVI-s: subVI_init and subVI_stay - the caller needs to invoke both, wire connections from the first to the second, except the "error out" line which must pass through Register For Events to make sure it will be done before invoking the subVI_stay.

Or - if the main reason for creating user event in the subVI was a sophisticated data structure used by the event, like large and possibly nested cluster (the problem is that creating the event in the caller would need access to an empty structure, and putting this in the caller might make the caller too big) - use a separate subVI_typedef.